# How do I get those small views from the bottom to appear in iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'n talking about the small windows with buttons that come from the bottom when you need to confirm some action. For example, if you want to delete a photo from an album and press the trash icon, a small view jumps from the bottom and asks if you want to delete the photo or cancel

How do I get those views to appear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a UIActionSheet.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Action"
                                           delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to look at the UIActionSheet object: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

An example here: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/